# Installing .NET SDK on Ubuntu produces no executable dotnet file

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dotnet

Installing .NET SDK on Ubuntu 20.04 with the commands listed in the [Install .NET on Ubuntu](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu#2004-) docs:

```
wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb
sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
rm packages-microsoft-prod.deb

sudo apt-get update; \
  sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https && \
  sudo apt-get update && \
  sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-6.0
```

produces no `dotnet` executable.

```
Command 'dotnet' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo snap install dotnet-sdk
```

Listing files from the package:

```
dpkg -L dotnet-sdk-6.0 | grep -P "dotnet$"
```

gives

```
/usr/share/dotnet
```

The `/usr/share/dotnet` directory contains no executable. I compared this result with my other Ubuntu installation where I installed dotnet ages ago, and there it is installed in `/usr/share/dotnet` *but there exists a* `/usr/share/dotnet/dotnet` executable.

What am I doing wrong? How to install `dotnet` on Ubuntu with APT?

**Using snap is not an option.**

Comment: Don't prematurely discard diagnostic information. Look at the whole `dpkg -L` output. Can you `apt-cache search dotnet` and install via `apt`?

Comment: @waltinator `dpkg -L` gives a lot of files, all of in `/usr/share/dotnet`. None of them are executables.

Comment: @waltinator apt-cache search dotnet gives a bunch of packages in 4 different versions of .NET (2.1, 3.1, 5.0, 6.0). Installing dotnet-sdk-6.0 autoinstalls related packages in 6.0 version. For completion, the other autoinstalled packages are:
dotnet-apphost-pack-6.0, dotnet-hostfxr-6.0, dotnet-runtime-6.0, dotnet-runtime-deps-6.0, dotnet-targeting-pack-6.0.

Answer (score 0):

So I had the same issue. I didn't find out what to do with apt problem but downloading sdk using snap works fine and create everything you need:

```
sudo snap install dotnet-sdk --classic
```

Probably you won't be able to use CLI but most IDEs will find path to your sdks and executable.